# My text can't move past the background image

Tags: html, css, spacing, blurry

I'm a newbie developer who is just starting to create his first actual web page, and I've run into a few problems. There's some text I put into a flexbox that won't go under the image.

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: white
}

#hero {
  background-image: url("river.webp");
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 10px 0 100px 0
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

.three {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 100px
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  <h1 class="title">This is Cypress!</h1>
  <div class="three">
    <h4>Lively malls</h4>
    <h4>Challenging Escape Rooms</h4>
    <h4>Relaxing on the lake</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding margins and padding to the top. However, the background image just enlarges with the text. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You've set the background image to cover the entire container. Sounds like you're better off using an inline image.

Comment: `background-size: cover` is telling the background image to cover the entire `#hero` div, no matter how big it gets. You could just set it as a background on the `h1` if that's the preference, or create another container around the `h1` and put the background image on that.

Comment: Specify the element where you want the background image. Or add a sample image

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.wrapper > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

.three {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2022/06/profile-picture.jpeg">
  <h1 class="title">This is Cypress!</h1>
  <div class="three">
    <h4>Lively malls</h4>
    <h4>Challenging Escape Rooms</h4>
    <h4>Relaxing on the lake</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hey,
I agree with [@ralph.m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031766/ralph-m) you should use a normal image tag to achieve this. I created a short snippet for you, let me know if it helps :)
You would need to change the img src attribute to your image.

EDIT:

```css
.three {
    color: #2337EC;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.three h4 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="three">
  <div>
    <img src="mall.jpg">
    <h4>Lively malls</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="escape.jpg">
    <h4>Challenging Escape Rooms</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="relax.jpg">
    <h4>Relaxing on the lake</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want you can try this one. Essentially I added the `<div>` around each content block in your `div.three` and added the css for your headings to be centered. Might look a little better, if you want to try :)

Comment: Hey guys. I'm not sure if y'all are still paying attention to this post, but I finished my first project thanks to you all. Although it, doesn't look as good as I hoped, and I didn't manage to do everything I wanted, I feel satisfied that I managed to come up with something. Here's the link if any one wants to take a look. https://precious-raindrop-414a06.netlify.app/

Comment: Hey :)
Awesome! Looks like a good start! :)
I will edit my answer and give you an example, how your `.three` div might look a bit nicer (with images over headline/vice versa)